# How to access the stream of an existing image on the screen?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm developing an App, and I want to get access to the stream of an existing Image on the Visual tree. I know how to access and obtain an stream from the FilePicker, but not from an existing Image on the screen.

I have this code but:

```
ImageSource originalImage = _originalImage.Source;
BitmapImage bitmapImage = (BitmapImage)originalImage;
var rass = await RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(bitmapImage.UriSource).OpenReadAsync();
```

This gives me the stream from the image, but It has to download twice, one for the Image on the screen, and other to get access to the stream, since I have the Image already download and visible on the screen.... How can I get access to its stream?

Comment: Can you just get the stream first, and then assign to the image?

Comment: But the good thing about the Image class, is that it caches the Images automatically. If I do what you say, I have to download only once time, right, but everytime I show a photo.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need to do this? Perhaps there is some other way to tackle your requirements? Is this a performance issues (for example)?

Comment: I want to extract the most common pixel color from the image, so I can put it as the background. I have an example working with the code behind, but I don't want to download twice the image, and I want to use the Image object because of it's caching capabilities.